# Smartly reshaping a dictionary to make a pandas data frame in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary structured as follows:

```
    {'Country_0_0': array([0.00205887, 0.00066778, 0.00018736, 0.00267426, 0.00167584,
        0.00325369, 0.00308424, 0.00240303, 0.00232662, 0.0018572 ,
        0.00291514, 0.00129124, 0.00213518, 0.00269184, 0.00019298,
        0.00275547, 0.00012562, 0.00274757, 0.0014712 , 0.00197154,
        0.00225755, 0.00088496, 0.00278242, 0.0011274 , 0.0023305 ,
        0.00098155, 0.00210151, 0.00025001, 0.0021463 , 0.00310724,
        0.00237708, 0.00026404, 0.00078338, 0.0007101 , 0.00080683,
        0.00092139, 0.00045451, 0.00162904, 0.00173966, 0.00230035,
        0.00123715, 0.00194307, 0.00115212, 0.0028666 , 0.00036725,
        0.00055788, 0.00017001, 0.00297113, 0.00099035, 0.00136376,
        0.00035665, 0.00199739, 0.00056606, 0.00170236, 0.00016059,
        0.00119921, 0.00161244, 0.00178576]),
 'Country_0_1': array([1.38911956e-03, 1.81695317e-03, 1.49397660e-03, 3.36493664e-03,
        1.29550916e-03, 2.78850386e-03, 1.46612675e-03, 2.67197959e-03,
        2.53572802e-03, 8.43125466e-04, 3.34165244e-03, 3.00652573e-03,
        2.16462098e-04, 4.58528408e-04, 2.19940753e-03, 1.32510923e-03,
        1.73144250e-03, 1.07272091e-03, 1.19183874e-03, 7.05209922e-04,
        1.82857134e-03, 9.19182407e-04, 3.16658232e-03, 3.74238075e-04,
        1.05319555e-04, 1.31983491e-03, 1.07057600e-03, 1.31814900e-05,
        1.97396178e-03, 2.97744450e-03, 7.69557528e-04, 5.81582604e-04,
        3.34432687e-04, 1.25960417e-03, 7.82230675e-04, 3.06447798e-03,
        2.54516178e-03, 1.52796734e-03, 1.30200934e-05, 2.81496539e-03,
        2.58522073e-04, 2.08142834e-03]), ...
'Country_221_95': array([...])
```

i.e., the keys of the dictionary are of the form: Country_countrynum_productnum. Each country has 96 products, so that the dictionary will be composed of keys made like that: Country_0_0, Country_0_1, Country_0_2 ...., Country_0_95, Country_1_0, Country_1_1,...Country_1_95, and so on until Country_221_0, Country_221_1, Country_221_2 ...., Country_221_95. Each key has a different number of elements (from 40 to 70). Now I aim to build up a pandas data frame made as follows:

```
Country_0          Country_1             Country_2 ...         Country_221
Country_0_0[0].    Country_1_0[0]        Country_2_0[0]        Country_221_0[0]
...                 ...                  ...                    ...
Country_0_0[k00]   Country_1_0[k10]      Country_2_0[k20]       Country_221_0[k22100]
Country_0_1[0]     Country_1_1[0]        Country_2_1[0]         Country_221_1[0]
...                ...                      ...                   ...
Country_0_1[k01]   Country_1_1[k11]       Country_2_1[k21]       Country_221_1[k2211]
...                ...                       ...                 ...
Country_0_95[0]    Country_1_95[0]        Country_2_95[0]       Country_1_95[0]
...                ...                         ...                 ...
Country_0_95[k095] Country_1_95[k195].    Country_2_95[k295]     Country_1_95[k22195]
```

Where k00, k01, ... are the number of elements within each key of the dictionary.

Comment: I can't visualize how would your dataframe looks like.

Comment: @igorkf thank you for the reply. Basically, I would like to form column i so that it contains all the values of the type Country_i_k for k ranging from 1 to 95. Hence, for instance, the first column should be named Country_0 and should contain all the values in Country_0_0, Couuntry_0_1,..., Country_0_95. Possibly an id should be included. I hope it is clearer. Please let me know.